# module controller does not respond!

Tags: page-controller

I'm trying to create a controller within my custom module, but the controller still doesn't response when visiting the associated path.

Here are my files:

#### my_module/my_module.routing.yml:

```
my_module.agreement:
  path: 'my_module/send_consent'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\MyModuleController::check_agreement'
    _title: 'Agreement controller'
  methods:  [GET]
```

#### my_module/src/Controller/MyModuleController.php :

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;


use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class MyModuleController extends ControllerBase {

    public function check_agreement() {
        die('hello from controller');
    }
}
```

To test I visit `myproject.local/my_module/send_consent`

Any help?

Comment: The question on this answer is not a duplicate, but the answer is relevant: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/224668/42650. Routes should begin with a slash.

Comment: In this case my controller serve Ajax there is no problem if slash was not figure in path field of routing YAML file while the Ajax request is sent to "my_domain/my_module/send_consent" that slash surely will be always present in the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot `requirements` (which is required):

```
my_module.agreement:
  path: 'my_module/send_consent'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\MyModuleController::check_agreement'
    _title: 'Agreement controller'
  methods:  [GET]
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

See [Structure of roots](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/structure-of-routes) for full details.

Comment: I thought it was optional! should we set permissions always to 'access content'??

Comment: @BrahimKhouy [You can click the tick to accept the answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: The permission is whatever you need to require to access that path.